# Check if something is a function before calling it

Tags: php

I have a class that looks a bit like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class FormatAddressController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['api-auth']);
        $this->middleware(['api-after']);
    }

    public function format(Request $request) {
        // TODO first, get customer settings to see what functions to run, and how to run them
        // but, assume that the settings come as an array where the key is the function name
        // and the value is one of NULL, false, or settings to pass through to the function
        $settings = ['isoAndCountry' => true, 'testFunc' => ['testSetting' => 'test setting value']];

        $address = $request->input('address');

        $errors = [];

        foreach ($settings as $funcName => $funcSettings) {    
            try {
                $address = $this->$funcName($funcSettings, $address); // every function has to return the modified address
            } catch(Exception $e) {
                $errors[$funcName] = $e;
            }

        }

        return response()->json([
            'address' => $address,
            'errors' => $errors
        ]);
    }

    public function isoAndCountry($settings, $address) {
        // TODO

        return $address;
    }
}
```

Now, when I call this function, isoAndCountry, through that settings loop I defined above, it works! It works just fine.

However I tried following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835627/php-is-function-to-determine-if-a-variable-is-a-function) and checking `is_callable` and... it errors:

```
            if (is_callable($this->$funcName)) {
                try {
                    $address = $this->$funcName($funcSettings, $address); // every function has to return the modified address
                } catch(Exception $e) {
                    $errors[$funcName] = $e;
                }
            }
```

How can I check if it's callable? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: what the error you got here ?

Comment: Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\FormatAddressController::$isoAndCountry

Comment: Try doing `call_user_func([ $this, $funcName ])` to avoid the complexities of operator precedence and evaluation order

Comment: @apokryfos is there any documentation to describe the complexities you're talking about? I'm relatively new to PHP and would like to learn what pitfalls to avoid and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `method_exists` here to check if the method really exists in the class.

```
foreach ($settings as $funcName => $funcSettings) {
    if (method_exists($this, $funcName)) {
        $this->$funcName($funcSettings, $address);
    }
}
```

The reason why `is_callable` will not work in your scenario is because Laravel controllers has a `__call` magic method which will handle undefined methods, so running `is_callable` on any non existing methods would return true.

Take the following class as an example:

```
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        var_dump(is_callable([$this, 'testFunc']));
    }
}
```

The output of `new A` would be `false`. However, if you add the following into the class:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    //
}
```

Now the output of the `var_dump` would return `true`.

You can read more about the `__call` scenario I've mentioned right here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php#118623

For more information about `__call`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Comment: Thanks for all the info . method_exists works ! very informative answer.

Answer (score 2):

May be this can also solve the problem :

```
 if(method_exists($this,$funcName)){ ... }
```

Comment: Yes, me too. Still, is_callable should have worked as well (https://3v4l.org/TNN70), so I'm wondering if something else is going on that we can't see.

Comment: the **testFunc** is missing ? isn't that ?

Comment: I thought that was the point. It's still in the `$settings` array in that example link, and is_callable verifies that it doesn't exist in the object so it doesn't get called.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if (is_callable([$this, $funcName])) { ...
```

instead.

The way you have it written with `is_callable($this->$funcName)`, it's going to look for a property called `$funcName` on `$this`, (which probably doesn't exist) and check if that's callable. If you use that array syntax it will evaluate the named method instead.

---

It may be simpler in this case to use

```
if (method_exists($this, $funcName)) {
```

since you're using it in another method of the same object, if the method exists it should be callable.

Comment: OK so I've done it the way you said, and when $funcName is isoAndCountry, it returns true, but... strangely, when $funcName iterates to the next item, testFunc, that ALSO returns true, even though I defined no testFunc function into the class. It returns true, tries to run the function, and then errors with `Method App\Http\Controllers\FormatAddressController::testFunc does not exist.`

Comment: Uh oh, I didn't think that would happen, sorry

Comment: Pretty strange though, huh? I didn't expect it either.

Comment: It returns false?

Comment: It's possible that it's because I'm in Laravel maybe?

Comment: I made this, based on your example (as closely as possible without the framework stuff) https://3v4l.org/TNN70

Comment: Maybe it's getting called directly somewhere else you aren't expecting?

Comment: You can have a look at my answer. I explain why `is_callable` will not work in his scenario. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to differentiate between class properties and methods. For example in this class:

```
class A {
    private $foo = null;

    public function getFoo() {
        return $this->foo;
    }
}
```

- the `private $foo` is property and can be checked by `property_exists()`
- the `public function getFoo()` is method and can be checked by `method_exists()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

I think that `$this->$funcName` works only for properties.